# Не отводи своих глаз

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ошибочны ли эти выражения: 
*Не отводи своих глаз, не опускай своих глаз, не оторвать глаз от зрелища*?

Answer (score 2):

Ни одно из приведенных вами предложений не является ошибочным, все они зафиксированы в словарях.

Не могу ***оторвать глаз*** от этого гнутого старика с ящиком: как несет он на плече куб чистого света… и эта черная собака рядом, по контрасту… [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

И тогда не нужно ***отводить глаз*** от ясных и измученных глаз мамы и не нужно притворяться, будто ничего не изменилось в жизни. [А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия (1943-1951)]

Тогда, взяв Чикилева за плечи, Митька с добрых полминуты вглядывался в рыжеватое, чуть склоненное перед ним на бочок лицо, так что только смертельная ненависть помогла тому ***не опустить глаз*** ...Чикилева. [Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Части 1-2 (1927)]

Comment: Очень большущее Вам спасибо!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

В первых двух выражениях лишнее слово "своих", поскольку о чужих глазах так нельзя сказать. Третье выражение допустимо, но слова "глаз не оторвать" более типичны по отношению к отдельному предмету, на котором можно сосредоточиться взглядом и которое радует глаз,  к тому же и здесь ясно, что без помощи "глаз" не обошлось (есть лёгкая тавтологичность). В случае "зрелища" важнее интерес к нему, а не изящный вид чего-то в нём, поэтому стилистически лучше сказать "не оторваться".

Comment: Александр, оторваться от чего-л не аналогично оторвать глаз, не оторвать зрелище. Никакой тавтологии здесь нет. По поводу ''своих'' согласен. Во-первых тавтология -это повторение одного и того же, во-вторых, если здесь была бы ошибка - то это был бы плеоназм.

Comment: В третьих, оторваться  используется и самостоятельно - в других значениях.